# Is there a formal way to solve probability questions involving permutation and combination such that we cover all possibilties without overcounting.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, measure-theory, problem-solving

I need a systematic way to solve questions involving permutation and combinations or I need a way to verify my solution.
Examples of problems: matching envelopes to people, how many people share a birthday, problems involving cards, etc.
I know about probability axioms. The problem is calculating the probability of events from permutations and combinations.
These two are concrete examples.

---

Eight indistinguishable rooks are randomly distributed on a chessboard. What is the probability that two rooks can attack each other?
The correct answer is $\frac{8!}{64 \choose 8}$ but I got
$\frac{2}{64 \choose 8}$
This happened because there I was not able to guess conditions where two rooks can attack each other despite not being on the same diagonal.
This is under-counting.

Another example :
There are 40 balls each with a number inscribed on them. Find the number of ways to choose 8 balls from the set such that only six of them have numbers between 1 to 8 inscribed on them.
Correct answer is $\frac{{8 \choose 2} {32 \choose2}}{40 \choose 8}$
but i got $\frac{{8 \choose 2} {38 \choose2}}{40 \choose 8}$ because I did not remove balls I chose previously
This was a case of over-counting.

---

I recognize these problems can be fixed by practice. I want to know if is there a way/algorithm to solve these problems with less involvement of logic using something like sets and or linear algebra.

If I apply the algorithm on the question involving rooks it should be immediately obvious that I am not considering the cases where two rooks can attack each other despite not being on a diagonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [twelvefold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way) is a good place to start. It provides a template for solving huge classes of elementary counting problems. Another useful, but more narrow, methodology is known as [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).